# Is it possible to improve the following GUI in Samsung Galaxy S

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, user-interface, samsung-touchwiz

I was wondering, is it possible for me to perform modification for the following GUI in Samsung Galaxy S? What software I should use to do so? (I use a white rectangle to highlight them)

1) Possible for me to remove button 1,2,3 numbering.

2) I do not want a square icon. Is it possible to have icon background same as wallpaper background?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an alternative homescreen launcher like [LauncherPro](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.fede.launcher&feature=search_result) or [dxTop](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.android.dxtop.demo.launcher&feature=search_result) or [ADW.Launcher](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.adw.launcher) or [GoLauncher](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex&feature=search_result).

Lots of customizations and options. You'll need to explore each one's features and see which is best for you.

Comment: +1 for LauncherPro, there are even custom skins/builds of LauncherPro to further customize the homescreen.

Comment: Here's a [link to LauncherPro](http://www.launcherpro.com/) for the search-engine-inept.

Comment: or [Zeam](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.zeam&feature=search_result).

Answer (score 2):

If you want those home screen indicators but just don't want the numbers in them then download [ADW.Launcher](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.adw.launcher&feature=search_result).  It comes pre-installed on CyanogenMod 6.2.1 and I've really enjoyed using it.

As far as that icon, it is what it is.  In order to change it you're going to need to alter the app directly, or install an app that allows you to change the icons for your apps with image files you have installed on your SDCard.