# What are the features that TouchWiz has that vanilla Android does not have?

Tags: samsung-touchwiz, vanilla-android

What are the features that [TouchWiz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TouchWiz) has that vanilla Android does not have?

This question is similar to [What are the features that HTC Sense has that vanilla Android does not have?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13580/what-are-the-features-that-htc-sense-has-that-stock-android-does-not-have) but for Samsung [TouchWiz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TouchWiz).

Comment: Good question.  I'd be inclined to say not much, but then I've barely used stock.  Did you have a particular version of TouchWiz in mind?

Comment: I would like to know about the latest released version

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Home Screen**

- Up to 7 Home screens, with the ability to add and remove screens at will, and drag them around to change the order (pinch zoom the home screen)
- Customizable dock area at the bottom of the home screen, allowing you to [add/remove up to 4 apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8094/how-do-i-replace-the-default-messaging-icon-in-the-dock-with-handcent/8098#8098).

**Apps List**

- 'Screen at a time' sideways scrolling apps list
- Rounded square backgrounds added to all app icons in the app list ([see here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7540/is-it-possible-to-improve-the-following-gui-in-samsung-galaxy-s))
- Pre-installed apps (or apps present during the last OS upgrade) are in alphabetical order, new apps are added at the end in the order they're installed.

**Home Button**

- Holding the <kbd>Home</kbd> button brings up a list of 6 recently used apps, along with a Task Manager button
- Holding the <kbd>Back</kbd> button and tapping the <kbd>Home</kbd> button takes a screenshot [on the Galaxy S](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/1765/156), for the [Galaxy SII use](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/14785/156) <kbd>Power</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>

**Samsung Widgets**

These are home screen widgets that Samsung include, and are in a separate Samsung Widgets category pre-Gingerbread, post-Gingerbread they are in the main Android Widgets list with the word "Samsung" under them instead of "Android". Exact widget selection varies depending on OS version and network.

- AccuWeather Clock
- Buddies Now (messaging shortcuts for nominated contacts)
- Calendar Clock
- Daily Briefing (News, weather, stocks, social media updates)
- Days (create new entries in the Diary app)
- Dual Clock
- Feeds and Updates
- Program Monitor
- Y! Finance Clock

**Samsung (and other) Bundled Apps**

- Samsung AllShare (DLNA)
- FM Radio (for models with hardware FM radio)
- Kies air (shares phone data, and allows control of some phone functions over wifi to a PC web browser, first pre-installed with Gingerbread, available in Samsung app store for older OSs)
- Memo (notepad app)
- Mini Diary (create diary pages with daily details, memos and photos)
- My Files (file manager)
- Samsung Apps (Samsung's own app store, currently only free content in there, but some of the apps are normally paid or ad-supported on the Android Market)
- Social Hub (messaging app combining email, SMS and social networks)
- Task Manager
- ThinkFree Office

**Modified Apps**

- Contacts (History and Activities tabs, linked to Social Hub and social network account updates, showing recent posts by contact and recent interactions with them)
- Gallery (interface to select either [scrolling wallpaper or static, portrait wallpaper](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13275/how-can-i-get-the-android-to-use-wallpapers-sized-to-my-screen-resolution/13286#13286))
- Music (Disc View interface added, allowing sideways scroll through albums showing the artwork on a "CD" shape)
- Videos (extra codec support DivX/Xvid in particular)

**Region specific TouchWiz features**

- Throughout most of Europe and Asia, Samsung's Mobile Tracker feature is included in the Security settings allowing remote password setting, tracking and wiping of mobiles registered on the http://samsungdive.com website

**Version specific TouchWiz features**

- Eclair (Android 2.1) - TouchWiz included Wifi tethering as a standard feature before it was brought to the main Android OS in v2.2.

(*except where noted, all from TouchWiz 3 on a Gingerbread Galaxy S*)

Comment: _Holding the `Back` button and tapping the `Home` button takes a screenshot_ <-- Are you about this one? Doesn't work on my SGS2 running 2.3.3. Holding the `Home` button and tapping the `Power` button does take a screenshot though.

Comment: Positive, on my original SGS with 2.3.3 (and for a few versions before that). Obviously Samsung can't make their minds up, more screen shot variations for other devices/versions here http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1759/how-to-take-a-screenshot-with-an-android-phone

Comment: @sabre23t: they forgot to say double tap. :) it works on sgs1, and it should also work on sgs2. hold the back button & double click the home.

Comment: @Petar: Just tried on my sgs2 the hold `back` button & double click `home` button. Nope, didn't get screen shot. Get "Voice talk, wake-up command" screen instead (you get the same when just double click `home` button).

Comment: Excellent summary. Now the question is whether or not these would be missed, should we root our devices to "self upgrade" to ICS.